# File not found in Directory (Static PDF attachment)

Tags: java, email

My requirement is with a generic PDF i have to attach a static PDF for an email , i can attach the generic PDF without any issues , but it is giving me an issue with static PDF while fetching it from the directory, i have tried several ways could you please assist ....

Below is error and the code related to it....

```
Error :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/How_to_access_member_information.pdf (No such file or directory)
```

**Code** :

```
try {
                File pdfFile = new File("//mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/How_to_access_member_information.pdf");
                byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) pdfFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
                fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
                fis.close();
                String registerId = notificationEngineService.registerFileOnNe("application/pdf", "How_to_access_member_information.pdf", bytesArray);
                System.out.println("registerId 1=============================== " + registerId);
                notificationEngineService.sendRegisteredAttViaNe(registerId, emailBody, dispInfo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception 10============================================================");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

```
    try {
        File pdfFile = new File("\\\\dcpcifs01\\DGB\\Correspondence\\Systems\\PROD_DOCS\\How_to_access_member_information.pdf");
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) pdfFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
        fis.close();
        String registerId = notificationEngineService.registerFileOnNe("application/pdf", "How_to_access_member_information.pdf", bytesArray);
        System.out.println("registerId 2=============================== " + registerId);
        notificationEngineService.sendRegisteredAttViaNe(registerId, emailBody, dispInfo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 10============================================================");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw new GroupRiskSystemException(ExceptionCode.COMPASS_ERROR.name());
}
return "";
```

}

```
private void sendEmail(MbsMembers memberObject) {
        try {
            System.out.println(" ======================Start0=================================== ");
            za.co.discoverygrouprisk.common.jaxb.email.AttachmentType attachmentType = new za.co.discoverygrouprisk.common.jaxb.email.AttachmentType();
            attachmentType.setMember(new MemberType());
            attachmentType.setCamundaProcessId("0");
            attachmentType.setFileName("How_to_access_member_information.pdf");
            attachmentType.setChildBusinessKey(0l);
            attachmentType.setNeID(0l);

            DGRMultiAttachmentEmailDetailV01 emailDetail = new DGRMultiAttachmentEmailDetailV01();

            SchemeDataType schemeDataType = new SchemeDataType();
            SchemeType schemeType = new SchemeType();
            SchemeNumberType schemeNumberType = new SchemeNumberType();
            schemeNumberType.setValue(01);
            schemeType.setSchemeNumber(schemeNumberType);
            schemeDataType.setScheme(schemeType);
            emailDetail.setSchemeData(schemeDataType);

            EmailDataType emailDataType = new EmailDataType();
            EmailType emailType = new EmailType();
            emailType.setSubject("How to access member information");
            emailType.setFromAddress("groupinfo@discovery.co.za");
            emailType.setToAddress(memberObject.getEmailAddress());
            emailDataType.setEmail(emailType);
            emailDetail.setEmailData(emailDataType);

            AttachmentDataType attachmentDataType = new AttachmentDataType();
//            attachmentDataType.setLocation("//mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/");
            attachmentDataType.setLocation("\\\\dcpcifs01\\DGB\\Correspondence\\Systems\\PROD_DOCS\\");
            //mnt/DGB/Correspondence/2020/QA/MEMBER_REQUIREMENT_LETTER
            attachmentDataType.setParentBusinessKey(01);
            attachmentDataType.getAttachment().add(attachmentType);
            emailDetail.setAttachmentData(attachmentDataType);

            EmailDataSource adHocDS = new AdHocEmailDataSource(emailDetail);
            String emailBody = createEmailBody(memberObject);
            StandardEmailTemplate template = new StandardEmailTemplate(emailBody);
            Email email = new StandardEmail(adHocDS, template);
            email.createEmail();

            email.sendEmail();

            System.out.println(" ======================End0=================================== ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" ======================Exception0=================================== ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below :

```
File pdfFile = new File("/mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/How_to_access_member_information.pdf");
```

Adding the below :

Create a directory under user home directory say : `/home/user_name/java-pdf`.
Then try the below code once to check if your code is able to access the file:

```
File homedir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File pdfFile = new File(homedir, "java-pdf/How_to_access_member_information.pdf");
```

The above code runs fine for me.

Comment: I used both linux directory and windows directory, both are giving the same error.

Comment: For a linux directory we use this way //mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/    so we cannot use your way to read , i confirmed that by using your way and it's also giving the same issue

Comment: How come your code able to access this : 

File pdfFile = new File("\\\\dcpcifs01\\DGB\\Correspondence\\Systems\\PROD_DOCS\\How_to_access_member_information.pdf");

Comment: No it's not accessing that location also , that what the issue is , it can't pick up directory.

Comment: @ManneManoj : I have updated my answer. I have run the code and I could successfully access the pdf file. Please try this once in your code as well. Create a location under user home directory. Read the path from System.getProperty method and the use the location as explained in my code. This works correctly for me.

Comment: Also try removing the double slash at the begin...Use this :  
`/mnt/DGB/Correspondence/Systems/PROD_DOCS/How_to_access_member_information.pdf`